# IE, sending 'this' argument by onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have onclick method in html which send 'this' to js function. At chrome it works and I can found closest("tr") element. But in IE browser I get an error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'

My html:

```
<td class="border-0" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 20px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SearchLossCodeDescDam(this);" tabindex="-1">
       <div title="Search Loss Code" class="img-responsive claim-ccc-search_bttn"></div>
    </a>
</td>
```

and js method:

```
function SearchLossCodeDescDam(s) {
    var row = s.closest("tr");
    .....
}
```

I made a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/b0oa9yL6/

Do you now how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing DOM object to javacript function. Convert DOM object to jQuery object to call `closest` on it. To get id from jQuery object you can use `attr()`

**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b0oa9yL6/4/)**

```
var row = $(s).closest("tr");
alert(row.attr("id"));
```

**Why it works in chrome**

This works in Chrome probably the chrome browser uses [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). That is why you are able to access the id property as `Element.closest` returns DOM not the jQuery object.

> The Element.closest() method returns the closest ancestor of the
>   current element (or the current element itself) which matches the
>   selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it
>   returns null.

Comment: any idea why it works with chrome without the jquery??

Comment: Because it is  Element.closest() , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest